# Coilguns as spaceship thrusters second attempt

Tags: science-fiction, physics, hard-science, spaceships, asteroids

This is a second attempt for this question, the first time i put in too many different things that ended up derailing the question.

I'm in the early stages of designing a scifi game and want to use as little handwavium as possible (without ruining the fun). The first part of the game takes place in the asteroid belt and includes handwavium in the form of being able to break down just about anything into individual atoms and using a 3d printers make everything from an ingot to a fighter craft.

Backstory: Your ship was sent in advance to build the infrastructure for our first colony at Proxima b. The follow on ship with the colonists was scheduled to arrive 1 year after you but after 2 years the captain decided to head back and find out what was going on. FTL comms don't exist and the experimental FTL drives that we were used maxes out at 40c (just over 1 month to get to Proxima Centauri and only works in interstellar space so the crew was all in cryo sleep for the trip. When you wake up you find the ship is badly damaged and floating in the asteroid belt.

The intended reaction mass is sabots with a shell of (~11.75% mass) Invar (FeNi 64/36% 8,100kg/m³ specific heat capacity peaks at 545j/kg K at 200C Curie temp of 230C) wrapped around (~88.25% mass) silica harvested from asteroids. Depending on the ship the blocks may be as small as 0.01m³ ~30kg or as large as 1m³ ~3,000kg.

The smallest drone has a single 5m long coil, followed by dual 10/15/20m, quad 20m, and quad 50m for the largest coils. The dual and quad 20m fire 0.1m³ (300kg) slugs, the 50m fires 1m³ (3 000kg) slugs, everything else is 0.01m³ (30kg). The power budget is 56MWh for the smallest, 112MWh for the duals, and 278MWh for the quads. All coils are up to 5m outer diameter. Oh, and these are only used in space so air friction isn't an issue.

So, finally, the question is how do i turn all that into newtons for thrust/deltaV calculations?

Edit: I found Luke Campbell's coilgun equation on several different coilgun questions. http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/spacegunconvent.php#id--Kinetic_Kill_Weapons--Coil_Guns
If i did the math right 398098J is enough to push a 3000kg slug to 1000m/s in a hair over 59 meters.
Did i get it right?

Comment: Invar's a very, very strange choice for reaction mass pellets. It's defining trait is a low coefficient of thermal expansion, which is pretty much irrelevant here. The properties you're interested in are electrical conductivity (about 5 thousand times worse than copper) or its magnetic properties (unimpressive permeability, fairly low Curie temperature, etc). And do you have a particular reason for manufacturing precision projectiles for reaction mass instead of just slinging mass out of a bucket which is braked within the mass driver and reloaded for another shot?

Comment: Your mass drivers are also rather short, and the projectile energies are quite out of scale with the projectile masses...your smallest drivers are nearly 5 times as efficient in their use of reaction mass, which raises the question of why the larger ones even exist. Anyway, the average thrust is determined by the average mass flow rate and the exit velocity of the mass driver. Projectile composition, density, temperature, mass, size...none of these matter.

Comment: Ah, but they do matter because some of the energy you put into the magnetic field will become waste heat. The higher the temp you can heat the slug the more energy you can impart. As for why invar, the is in the asteroid belt where most iron you find will have quite a bit of nickle already in it unlike deposits on Earth.

Comment: The different sized mass drivers and slugs exist because they are pushing vastly different sized ships. Everything from a 8x16m drone to a 50x105m main module to multiple 50x70m modules. While yes there are vastly better options available these are made from the most common materials found in the asteroid belt.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff sorry, i mess up when posting the question. The power budgets should have been in MWh.

Comment: I suspect that if you really optimize for the most efficient projectile to launch from an electromagnetic engine, you'll just end up recreating ion engines.

Comment: @Cadence Sure, if maximum efficiency was the goal it would probably end up with Ion. But, it would take a truly ludicrous number of ion engines to push a ship that is anywhere near the size of these things. There also isn't a whole lot of Xenon gas floating around the asteroid belt. There is however literal tons of Iron/Nickel/silica.

Comment: BTW, mass drivers are great in terms of cheap operation -- but with real world parts, not even as good as chemical rockets in terms of getting anywhere.  More thrust than an ion engine, but the reaction mass runs out a lot quicker.

Comment: Some asteroids have a lot of nickel, not all, and a system that separates the bucket from the propellant could use any waste mass, as well as allowing you to use better magnet materials to allow more acceleration. Even if you use nickel as reaction mass, it doesn't make invar a good choice...there are much better iron-nickel alloys for the purpose. Invar is a very specific alloy that is not especially good for magnets.

Comment: And you missed my point about the projectile energies and masses. Your larger drivers would require drastically more propellant than a bunch of the smaller drivers consuming the same power. There's an energy efficiency versus propellant efficiency trade, and it doesn't really make sense for the smaller drivers to be the higher velocity ones, since it's the bigger ships that can mount longer mass drivers.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I think i see where the miscommunication is now. These are coilguns not railguns (the kind of mass drivers you are describing). There is no bucket or other part that can be kept for reusability. You get a little worse performance but on the other hand since nothing ever touches the coils you don't have the issue or rails being torn up every few shots. Also, in the longer ones you can split the power between multiple coils that each add part of the acceleration.

Comment: And unless i totally misunderstood how they work 5 coils at 20% of the power will give more acceleration than a single coil at 100% power which is the point of the longer ones on the larger ships.

Comment: No, I am not thinking of a railgun. The highest performing mass drivers accelerate a projectile by inducing currents in coils in the projectile, rather than relying on magnetization of the projectile. These relatively complex and high performance structures can be made part of a captive bucket which is decelerated regeneratively within the accelerator, allowing it to accelerate any kind of payload and to use things like superconducting coils to produce very strong accelerating fields with much lower losses.

Comment: And you can't compensate for a lack of energy by adding more coils, unless the smaller ones are horribly inefficient, and there doesn't appear to be a good reason that they would *need* to be that inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

Newton's third law can be written (using the 2nd law) as $\vec F_1 = m_1 \times \vec a_1 = -\vec F_2 = m_2 \times a_2 $ -- use that and conservation of momentum.

Each block is thrown at some velocity $\vec v$, so has a momentum of $\vec p = m \times \vec{v}$ -- that means it gives the same momentum (in [kg m/s]) to the ship that tossed it. But momentum $\vec p$ is also $\vec p = \int \vec F dt = \vec F \times t$, so you calculate the length of time it takes to accelerate the block (assume half final velocity over the length of the driver -- it'll be close enough) and back out the force required to get that velocity in that time.

Reaction on the drive (hence the ship) will be the same magnitude in the opposite direction *for each single block*.  Then calculate how many blocks per second (or other convenient time interval) you need to toss to get the overall acceleration you want/need as well as how long your reaction mass (i.e. store of premade blocks) will last while accelerating.

Knowing the force (either for a single shot or averaged over time) will get you the acceleration of the ship after dividing by the mass of ship plus remaining reaction mass store.  The [rocket equation](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/ideal-rocket-equation) will give you the total delta-V you can get from a given capacity of blocks or the actual delta-V obtained by using any fraction of the available reaction mass.

Comment: you used 2nd law formula, fixed it to the composite 2nd/4rd law variant. 2nd is "F=ma" and 3rd law is "action = reaction"

Comment: Thanks, @Trish.  I never bothered to write those as vectors for calculation purposes, but that's surely more correct than treating them as scalars -- though I'm not sure how relevant it is to this question.

Comment: it's basically irrelevant because the question is along one axis, but it might be relevant in case the railgun (or in case of multiple: their averaged out centerpoint) is not through the center of mass of the ship - that'd create a turning momentum $\vec M$

Comment: And unless that's due to damage -- say from a minor collision -- you'd then have to go all the way back to Earth to shoot the engineers...

Comment: ...or one engine failing, at which point engineers are to be shot too!

Comment: There are good principles but I would like an example solved; specifically the conversions to Newtons as stated in the OP.

Comment: If you're using kilograms and meters per second, you get Newtons automatically.  1 N = 1 kg x m/s^2 all day.  Unless you're Mars Climate Observer...

Comment: Good answer. I would add that the launching ship probably wants shock absorbers around the gun. This solution is a little like the original Orion Project concept, where they spat nukes out the backside and used it's pressure against a plate for propulsion.

Comment: @RobertRapplean Lots easier to restock on rock-in-a-bucket than on small nukes, though -- especially at 4 light years from home.

Comment: @RobertRapplean Seems unnecessary -- the small driver gives lower velocity than a rifle, with a 30 kg projectile, in a similar time frame to the barrel time of a rifle bullet.  Shouldn't need any more recoil absorption than a naval 5 inch rifle...

Comment: If you're talking about using it to propel a spaceship of any significant size, then either it'll jar the ship, or it won't provide meaningful acceleration. I wasn't suggesting nukes, just the shock absorbers.

Comment: And I was suggesting it's a solved problem, since about 1895.

Answer (score 3):

### let me cut to the needed parts...

> The smallest drone has a single 5m long coil, followed by dual 10/15/20m, quad 20m, and quad 50m for the largest coils. The dual and quad 20m fire 0.1m³ (300kg) slugs, the 50m fires 1m³ (3 000kg) slugs, everything else is 0.01m³ (30kg). The power budget is 56MWh for the smallest, 112MWh for the duals, and 278MWh for the quads. All coils are up to 5m outer diameter. Oh, and these are only used in space so air friction isn't an issue.

The composition doesn't matter, the material doesn't matter. All that matters is the mass, weight and ejection force.

1. $\vec F=m\vec a$ - Newton's 2nd law
2. $\vec F_1=-\vec F_2$  - Newton's 3rd law "action = reaction"

F is measured in **Newtons**.

You give us the devices' *power budgets* in MWh, which is actually easily convertible into their energy in Joules: 1 kWh is 3.6 MJ, so 1 MWh is 3600 MJ, your smallest drive brings 201 600 MJ to the table. That is the *Work* the device delivers. Assuming 100% efficiency, we can use that as the work that is used to accelerate the projectile. Work is defined as Force times the distance it is moved:

3. $|\vec F|=F$ & $|\vec a|=a$ - For simplicity, we use the length of the force and acceleration, as we look at a single axis: the one along the coilgun. If that is not through the center of mass, you need to calculate a lot more... later.
4. $W=F s$ - Work (is a scalar, not a vector!)

So, we have everything we need to solve the force each shot does have!

5. $F=W / s=\pu{201600 MJ} / \pu{5m}=40320\times \pu{10^3 \frac{kg\ m}{s^2}}$
6. $a_0=F / m=40320\times \pu{10^3 \frac{kg\ m}{s^2}} / \pu{300 kg} = 134.4 \times \pu{10^3 \frac{m}{s^2}}$

$1.3\times \pu{10^5 \frac{m}{s^2}}$ in lower than  the acceleration you get from [a conventional gun](https://hypertextbook.com/facts/2003/MichaelTse.shtml). So, we have the (linear) acceleration the projectile gets. From that we can calculate the time it has in the barrel:

7. $s=s_0+v_0t+a_0t^2$ - the basic movement formula, solve for time with known $s_0=0$ and $v_0=0$
8. $t_{exit}=\sqrt {s_{exit} / a_0}=\sqrt {\pu{5m} / {134.4 \times \pu{10^3 \frac{m}{s^2}}}}=\pu{0.006099 s}$

So, our projectile has one 164th of a second in the device. How much momentum does it give the ship? Let's do some conversion math starting with

9. $p=m\times v(t_{exit})$ - the standard formula for impulse, now we apply all those formulas 5 to 8 in reverse order:
10. $p=m\times (a_0 t)=m\times (a_0 \sqrt{s/a_0})=m\times ( \sqrt{s \times a_0})=m\times \sqrt{s\ F/m}=m\times \sqrt{s\ (W/s)/m}=m\times \sqrt{W/m}=\sqrt{W \times m}$
11. $p=\sqrt{\pu{201 600 MJ} \times \pu{30 kg}}=\sqrt{6048\times \pu{10^9 \frac kg^2m^2/s^2}}\approx\pu{\pu{77769 kNs}}$

Now, to see how fast your ship goes after each shot is simple!

12. $m_{ship}(t)=m_{dry}+N(t)\times m_{projectile}$ where N(t) is the number of shots left at the moment t.
13. $\Delta v_{ship}(t)=m_{ship}(t+1) / p$ - This is the speed change if you shoot one projectile at the time t.

Comment: Might just mention that the mass block is accelerating at about the same rate as a rifle bullet would in the barrel.  13000+ G.  Hope that Invar doesn't soften much as it heats, or you might have a problem with the buckets stripping off the stone.

Comment: @ZeissIkon yeeea, no. 134 kilometers per seconds-squared over 0.006 seconds... we are accelerating **less** harsh than a normal projectile.

Comment: Yep.  Been dropping decimal points since slide rules were the usual tool...  That's only 1340 G (give or take), about 1/8 what a 7.62x51 bullet pulls.

Comment: So, 77 769 000 divided by the total mass would give m/s acceleration from that shot? Oh, and i seem to have said something and meant something else in the question. Those power budgets are the entire amount the batteries store (preferably using less than half to accelerate and the other half to decelerate), not the budget for each shot.

Comment: @Rasip "Those power budgets are the entire amount the batteries store (preferably using less than half to accelerate and the other half to decelerate), not the budget for each shot.": that's something of a problem: your largest 1 TJ battery contains a pitifully small amount of energy when it comes to moving a spacecraft.

Comment: @Rasip Batteries are never counted in MWh. MWh is for *work*. Batteries have a capacity, capacities are given in Ampere-hours, which is different.

Comment: @Trish Wh or joules are an entirely reasonable way to rate battery capacity. For this application and many others, ampere-hours would only be meaningful when combined with the cell voltage to get units of energy.

Comment: @Rasip Basically, if by "battery" you mean an electrochemical device producing electricity from chemical reactions, this just isn't going to work. Such a thing just isn't going to approach the energy density of tanks of chemical propellant even on its own, it'll be far worse when you account for the reaction mass being separate. Batteries could be useful for accumulating the energy needed for each shot from some lower-power energy source like a reactor or solar array, but not for storing the energy needed for an entire interplanetary flight.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff even there I'd actually make the ship hull a giant capacitor by making conventional gap capacitors part of the structure of the ship...

Comment: @Trish capacitors in general have very poor energy density (storing energy essentially mechanically as charges on separate plates instead of in chemical bonds), and vacuum capacitors aren't especially high energy density for capacitors. Many dielectrics combine higher breakdown voltages, higher permittivity, and mechanical support allowing thinner plates. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_types#Dielectrics

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff true, but you have an entire ship hull that can be made from dielectric capacitor plates, which is a ginormous volume.

Comment: @Trish Say the ship is 10x10x100 m, 4200 m^2 of surface area. Approximating as a parallel plate capacitor, giving it a 1 mm gap, capacitance is about 37 microfarads, max voltage is 40 kV (with no safety margin), for stored energy of about 300 kJ. That's pretty much the equivalent of a small box of high voltage film capacitors. Oh, and your hull is charged to 40 kV and any dent will cause it to catastrophically discharge.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff All of them have solar panels, and all but the smallest drone also has various numbers of RTG/reactors making 250KW each. The batteries currently are NiMH that have 300 Wh per liter. Far better, but at twice the weight of lithium ion batteries, but again everything needed for them is fairly abundant in the asteroid belt.

Comment: @Rasip I think you're going to want to drastically rethink how you've scaled things. A 1 TJ NiMH battery will mass over 2 thousand metric tons. Launch smaller projectiles more often and you can reduce the battery size.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff 2000 metric tonnes is nothing with ships this size. Assuming i didn't drop a place somewhere on my scratch paper, the outer shell (armor, structure, radiators) alone is well over 11.6 megatons.

Answer (score 0):

More as a comment:

- *handwavium in the form of being able to break down just about anything into individual atoms and using a 3d printers make everything from an ingot to a fighter craft.*

Not so much of a hanwavium, I would say. All 3d printing is a bit a handwavium, but also it depends on tech, and the angle we define it as all 3d printing - as 3d printing tools of production to start actual production also can be considered 3d printing in some way.

As for the q, Trish way too complex much(but kudos for efforts, that for sure).

Things are simple, what is conserved is an impulse, meaning mass multiplied by change of velocity, which, the change of the velocity, at its max is known as delta-v.

Conservation means that mass of a ship multiplied by ship velocity change is equal to projectile mass multiplied by its exhaust velocity.

And as rough estimation all there is needs to know is exchaust velocity of a projectile, which does not depends that much on reactor power output, but a function of design of the whole system (capacitors and such can reduce demand on max reactor power output and it will be, most likely, an improvement as it may save mass thus imroving delta-v and acceleration time)

If reactors are soo good at delivering 56MW for small drones, then it makes sense to use ion based engines, to which any asteroid mass can be a reactive mass. You can use everything you do not need in this asteroid(oxygen as an example, which about 40-60% of asteroid mass) to be expelled for purposes of reactive propulsion.

And in a sense ION engines are mass drivers, but with a higher exchaust velocity of reactive mass and thus higher delta-v.

It may be ok to have not a high delta-v engines, being in asteroid belt - depends on curcumstances and constraints purposes.

As side note, 1km/s slugs are quite low velocity, which means also low delta-v which may be fine in a belt, to get from one worked out asteroid to another, but it will take its time, as they quite sparse placed(say no to starwars asteroid belts!) and in that sense ION engines are not loosing anything compared to those railgus - they save more mass for you and won't have worse time for moving from one asterid orbit to another, so as they are fine for hopping from close asteroids chunks 1-10km apart (sure it slower ther but, it not how you establish a connection between those two chunks on regular basis, so it is fine for some particular cases)

As means to deliver asteroid mass to some main asteruid factory, those railguns, mounted on an asteroid, can be viable option to gather mass to be processed. But it needs to evaluate what can be done from one cubic km asteroid, 1% iron content from it means about 0.5% of this planet annual steel production, industry for few billon people, so that 1% of asteroid stuff is something on the level of an industrial city of 10's of million people. So one asteroid of that size can be quite self sufficient productiin facility which does not need any external materials delivered, or moved away.